# Cloud formation template for delta lake tables using Aws glue crawler 'Invalid delta target with empty delta tables' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-glue-crawler

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
```

Description: **Delta lake tables using aws glue crawler**

```
Resources:
  Crawl:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      Name: crawler_name
      DatabaseName: database_name
      Role: role_arn
      Targets:
        DeltaTargets:
          - DeltaTables: 
            - S3_path_for_delta_table_folder (having deltalogs as child inside)
          - WriteManifest: True
```

> I am expecting to create delta table with symlink with write manifest
> file enable. I am able to do with aws console but failing in cft with
> same data path

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below CloudFormation to create a Crawler for
Delta source to create the manifest.

I added the below property to enforce as non native Delta Table and tested it which works as expected :

> CreateNativeDeltaTable : false

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Delta lake tables using aws glue crawler
Resources:
  MyDeltaCrawler:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      Name: "DeltaCrawler"
      Role: "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/GlueServiceRole"
      Tags: 
        "env": "dev1"
      DatabaseName: "default"
      Targets:
        DeltaTargets: 
          - CreateNativeDeltaTable: false
            DeltaTables: 
            - s3://your-bkt/path/to/delta/
            WriteManifest: true
```